# magento 2 how to fill general information of store programmatically?

Tags: magento2, stores, scopeinterface

I wan't to fill information of a store , this information:

1. Store Name

   Store Phone Number

   Country

   Region/State

   Postal Code
   City

   Street Address

I know how to get this information like below:

```
public function getStorename()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/name',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

 public function getStoreEmail()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
```

is there a method called `setValue()` ?

greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found the way to do this:

```
//Store Information
         $websiteId = $website->getId();
         $this->config->saveConfig('general/store_information/name',"Tienda H",'webistes',$websiteId);
         $this->config->saveConfig('general/store_information/phone',"4441842816",'webistes',$websiteId);
         $this->config->saveConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email',"tiendah@hotmail.com",'webistes',$websiteId);
         $this->config->saveConfig('general/store_information/postcode',"tiendah@hotmail.com",'webistes',$websiteId);
         $this->config->saveConfig('general/store_information/city',"San Luis Potosí",'webistes',$websiteId);
         $this->config->saveConfig('general/store_information/region_id',"tiendah@hotmail.com",'webistes',$websiteId);
         $this->config->saveConfig('general/store_information/street_line1',"Av de Prueba 122",'webistes',$websiteId);
```

use `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;` for config model